# Update haystack index on record deletion without re-indexing entire database

Tags: python, elasticsearch, django-haystack

Is it possible to update an entire haystack index without re-indexing the entire database? I have a database of 2.6 million records, each with related tables. If I run:

```
 python manage.py update_index --remove
```

I have to wait several days for indexing to complete, when there might only be one or two records that actually need re-indexing. Any solutions?

UPDATE:
As Bennylope says I can use get_updated_field to index only new entries. The problem arises if I delete a record, and want only that item to be removed from the index. How do I do this?

Comment: did you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove object from haystack index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66387251/6143954)

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions: add a modification timestamp to your primary records and make use of the [`get_updated_field`](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchindex_api.html#SearchIndex.get_updated_field) field method in  your `SearchIndex` to filter the queryset by recency of update using the `--age` flag in executing the [management command](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/management_commands.html#update-index).

The second would be to implement real time or [queued indexing](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/best_practices.html#use-of-a-queue-for-a-better-user-experience) to index individual records as they're updated.

Comment: See update in the question. The problem arises if I delete a record, and want only that item to be removed from the index. How do I do this?

Comment: I think a real time or queued option would be the way to go then.

Comment: What I am really looking for is a way to only remove deleted entries from the index. Do you have some sample code I could use? I am having massive trouble getting remove_object and should_update to work.